# How to run a default provided Dataflow template in gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

How do I run a gcloud command that will create a Dataflow job from a default template? e.g. Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery. I can do this via the console but looking to get this done via command line if possible?

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs run mydataflowjob \
--gcs-location ... \
--parameters ... \
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I downloaded the template from GCP's Github and moved to a storage bucket:

```sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java
```

```sh
export BUCKET_URI=gs://mybucketname && \
export TEMPLATE_NAME=PubSubToBigQuery.java && \
gsutil cp $TEMPLATE_NAME $BUCKET_URI && \
```

Then passed bucket file path to `--gcs-location`

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs run $DATAFLOW_NAME \
--gcs-location $BUCKET_URI/$TEMPLATE_NAME \
--parameters \
topic=projects/$PROJECT_ID/topics/$BQ_DATASET_NAME-$BQ_TABLE_NAME,\
table=$PROJECT_ID:$BQ_DATASET_NAME.$BQ_TABLE_NAME
```

Need to figure out how to pass a temp location (perhaps something to do with service account permissions? For another thread though...)

#### Edit

The default templates are located here in fact: `gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/PubSub_to_BigQuery`

So code to run job would be:

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs run $DATAFLOW_NAME \
--gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/PubSub_to_BigQuery \
--region us-central1 \
--staging-location $BUCKET_URI/temp \
--parameters \
inputTopic=projects/pubsub-public-data/topics/taxirides-realtime,\
outputTableSpec=$PROJECT_ID:$BQ_DATASET_NAME.$BQ_TABLE_NAME
```